# Android - Build flavor specific code and views

Tags: android, jackson, android-productflavors

I have an atlas application that has some specific parts depending on the atlas used. Let's basically describe it as:

- One map activity to show places
- One place details activity to show the place details

I am using flavors to build the applications corresponding to each atlas. For instance:

- One restaurants flavor
- One sightseeing site flavor

Each atlas gets its data from a different server URL and although the API is the same, the JSON returned has some specific parts when dealing with the place details:

- restaurants have JSON attributes like opening_time, food_type, ... e.g.:

  `{ "name": "", lat: "", lon: "", "opening_time": "", "food_type": "" }`
- Sightseeing sites have JSON attributes like access_type, altitude, ... e.g.:

  `{ "name": "", lat: "", lon: "", "access_type": "", "altitude": "" }`

I am using Jackson for JSON parsing and reached the point where:

- I finished parsing all common attributes and showing them inside the details activity.
- Respective servers get called properly (specifying the URL as a BuildConfig constant in Gradle).

#### The question

I am pretty new to build flavors and I am wondering which is the best way to deal with the flavor specific code (both Jackson parsing and detailled views). I mean cleanest with as little code repetition possible.

#### What I did so far:

For the views, I feel I could simply merge a layout XML which will be overriden for each variant. That seems to do the trick.

For java code, I am still quite lost. Maybe something like

```
class Place {
  @JsonProperty("name")
  String name;

  @JsonUnwrapped
  Details details;
}
```

But how to get that Details implementation specific to the flavor without duplicating the common Place code and parsing annotations? i.e. that:

- Restaurant flavor uses `com.atlas.restaurant.Details`
- Sightseeing flavor uses `com.atlas.sightseeing.Details`

PS: I can't change anything about the API and server code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No answer, so here is how I did it:

#### 1. Create the `com.example.model.Place` class in the main source set as

```
class Place {
  @JsonProperty("name")
  String name;

  @JsonUnwrapped
  Details details;
}
```

#### 2. Create a `com.example.model.Details` class for the `restaurant` flavor source set

```
class Details {
      @JsonProperty("opening_time")
      String openingTime;
}
```

#### 3. Create a `com.example.model.Details` class for the `sightseeing` flavor source set

```
class Details {
      @JsonProperty("access_type")
      String accessType;
}
```

#### 4. Workflow

open the "Build variants" panel and choose the flavor you are working on. Then the appropriate source sets will be picked. When done with a flavor, you can switch to the other one and if a class is missing, you'll get the warnings and errors that indicate it.